# bool() operator on nested lists which are empty

Tags: python

I understand the intuition of how `bool([])` is `False`.

But the why is `bool([[]])`, `bool([[[]]])`, etc are all `True`? What's the logic behind this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Empty list `[]` is falsy.

`[[]]` is a non-empty list with one element - an empty list. Hence `[[]]` is true.

See [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

`[[]]` is a list containing one list. `[[]]` is non-empty:

```
>>> len([[]])
1
```

It is a list of falsy objects, this is true, still it is non-zero.

For containers, you can think of `bool()` as the *"contains something"* operator.

Answer (score 1):

On a list, `bool(l)` is equivalent to `len(l) > 0`. It's not `any(bool(i) for i in l)` or some such test that looks at the items in the list.

Answer (score 1):

`bool([])` because it is an empty list. Think about it as checking `bool(len(L))`.
The list is empty - the length of the list is `0`, therefore the `bool` is `False`

On the other hand, `[[]]` is an list that contains an item - the item itself is an empty list, but the outer list contains that item. Therefore, the outer list is not empty (it contains an empty list). The length of the list is `1`, not `0`. Therefore, the `bool` of that list is `True`.

It would be the same, if we were talking about a list that contained all false values:

```
[False, False, False, False, False]
```

Similarly:

```
[[], [], [], [], [], []]
```

In both cases, the truth value of the list is `True`. However, `any(i for i in outer_list)` will return `False`

Answer (score 0):

Just because `[[]]` and `[[[]]]` are not empty lists , watch this:

```
l = []
for el in l:
    print (el) # prints nothing
```

But:

```
l = [[]]
for el in l:
    print(el) # prints [] that means list is not empty
```

Because of that :

```
l = []
not a # True
l = [[]]
not a # False
```

Answer (score 0):

Alongside the other answers that explained the reason, here is a recursion approach which returns false for nested untrue objects:

```
from collections import Iterable

def nested_bool(item):
    if not isinstance(item, Iterable) or isinstance(item, basestring):
        if not item:
            return False
        return True
    return any(nested_bool(i) for i in item)
```

Demo :

```
>>> nested_bool([[], [[], [[[['']]]]]])
False
>>> 
>>> nested_bool([[], [[], [[[['','']]]]]])
False
>>> 
>>> nested_bool([[], [[], [[[['',1]]]]]])
True
>>> 
>>> nested_bool([[], [[], [[[[]]]]]])
False
```